# device tree generation for embedded linux

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux, xilinx, device-tree

i am new to embedded linux development environment. I am trying to generate the device tree file for Zedboard(Zync Series SoC from Xilinx) and encountered the following line in the .dts file:

```
chosen {
    bootargs = "console=ttyPS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw earlyprintk rootfstype=ext2 rootwait devtmpfs.mount=0 consoleblank=0";
    linux,stdout-path = "/amba@0/serial@e0001000";
} ;
```

What is each parameter doing here?

Comment: Consider having a look though [the spec](https://www.devicetree.org/), although admittedly it's not particularly beginner-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to device tree use in Linux, then a good place to start learning is the [Booting the Linux-ppc kernel without Open Firmware](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/booting-without-of.txt?id=refs/tags/v4.9-rc1) (named so for legacy reasons, device tree is now used across several architectures).

The `chosen` node (documented formally [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/chosen.txt?id=refs/tags/v4.9-rc1)) is "special" and carries information to be passed from firmware/bootloader to the kernel. Or in this case, hard-wired into a static device tree beforehand.

`bootargs` holds the kernel command line, and `linux,stdout-path` (or these days just stdout-path) specifies which device the kernel should use as its default console. (Interestingly, the example you provide then overrides this on the command line...)